# How to find the curl, divergence, gradient and laplacian of functions without calculating the individual indices

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I know the definitions of the $\nabla$ operators but I don't understand how to find something like this:

Given the wave equation $\vec E = \vec a \sin(\vec k \cdot \vec r - \omega t)$
find $\vec \nabla (\vec \nabla \cdot \vec E)$

I could start calculating it all in components but that seems a bit unnecessary since the $\nabla$ operator is comparable to taking the derivative to $\vec r$. I just don't understand what the difference between $\vec \nabla$, $\vec \nabla\cdot$, $\vec \nabla\times$ and $\vec\nabla^2$ would be.

Comment: In general you must compute all the ingredients. Only in very special cases you can use some identities of vector calculus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that if $a$ is a constant vector,
$$ \nabla \cdot (af) = \partial_i (a_i f) = a_i \partial_i f = (a \cdot \nabla)f = a \cdot (\nabla f), $$
using summation convention. You also then have that if $f$ is a function of $k \cdot r$, then
$$ (\nabla f(k \cdot r))_i = \partial_i f(k_j r_j) = k_j (\partial_i r_j) f'(k_j r_j) = k_j \delta_{ij} f'(k_j r_j) = (k f'(k \cdot r))_i, $$
using the chain rule. These two identities should make it much easier for you to compute $\nabla(\nabla \cdot E)$.